# Unspecified error in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: magento, internet-explorer-11

I am using Magento CE 1.9 for my local project. The project works fine in all the browsers except IE11. When the page loads it gives following error:

> SCRIPT16389: Unspecified error.

In inspect element section the error is coming in HEAD tag of the webpage. I even checked the log, did not find anything related to it. I do not know which javascript/jquery code is causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

After debugging for hours, I found from where the issue was coming. It was coming due to the functions.js applied for the grayscale effects on the images. The grayscale filters are not working on IE10 and IE10+. The function which caused the issue "function grayscaleIE10(src)":

```
    // Grayscale images only on browsers IE10+ since they removed support for CSS grayscale filter
if (getInternetExplorerVersion() >= 10){
    jQuery('.grscale').each(function(){
        var el = jQuery(this);
        el.css({"position":"absolute"}).wrap("<div class='img_wrapper' style='display: inline-block'>").clone().addClass('img_grayscale').css({"position":"absolute","z-index":"5","opacity":"0"}).insertBefore(el).queue(function(){
            var el = jQuery(this);
            el.parent().css({"width":this.width,"height":this.height});
            el.dequeue();
        });
        this.src = grayscaleIE10(this.src);
    });

    // Quick animation on IE10+ 
    jQuery('.grscale').hover(
        function () {
            jQuery(this).parent().find('img:first').stop().animate({opacity:1}, 200);
        }, 
        function () {
            jQuery('.img_grayscale').stop().animate({opacity:0}, 200);
        }
    );  

    function grayscaleIE10(src){
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var imgObj = new Image();
        imgObj.src = src;
        canvas.width = imgObj.width;
        canvas.height = imgObj.height; 
        ctx.drawImage(imgObj, 0, 0); 
        var imgPixels = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        for(var y = 0; y < imgPixels.height; y++){
            for(var x = 0; x < imgPixels.width; x++){
                var i = (y * 4) * imgPixels.width + x * 4;
                var avg = (imgPixels.data[i] + imgPixels.data[i + 1] + imgPixels.data[i + 2]) / 3;
                imgPixels.data[i] = avg; 
                imgPixels.data[i + 1] = avg; 
                imgPixels.data[i + 2] = avg;
            }
        }
        ctx.putImageData(imgPixels, 0, 0, 0, 0, imgPixels.width, imgPixels.height);
        return canvas.toDataURL();
    };
};
```

Any ideas how to modify this function for IE10 & IE10+?
I have also referred to the other examples and demos for the grayscale effect. I was hoping if there is any way to modify this particular function without changing js and css files.